# Exception Logger - Filter Password in Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, password-protection

I'm using [Exception logger](http://rubygems.org/gems/r3_exception_logger) to get the exceptions, save in DB and display it.

While displaying in the Exceptions page, the password that the user has entered is visible in the request parameters. Any idea how to Filter it?

Also I have added

```
config.filter_parameters += [:password]
```

in the application.rb file. This helps me to filter password in log, but not in the exceptions that is filtered.